# работа с функцией c++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, функции

есть функция

```
    double* Probability(int r)
```

вот ее тело

```
double* Probability(int r)
{
    double p[3][3] =
    {
        {0.3, 0.15, 0.6},
        {0.1, 0.4, 0.12},
        {0.2, 0.27, 0.31}
    };
    double* P = new double[r];
    //double* P[9];
    int z = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= r; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= r; k++)
            {
                if ((i + j + k) == 3)
                {
                    P[z] = p[0][0] * p[0][1] * p[0][2];
                    //cout << P[z]<<" ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 4)
                {
                    P[z] += p[0][0] * (1 - p[0][1]) * p[1][1] * p[0][2];
                    //cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 5)
                {
                    P[z] += (1 - p[0][0]) * (1 - p[1][0]) * p[2][0] * p[0][1] * p[0][2];
                    //cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 6)
                {
                    P[z] += (1 - p[0][0]) * (1 - p[1][0]) * p[2][0] *
                            (1 - p[0][1]) * p[1][1] * p[0][2];
                    //cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 7)
                {
                    P[z] += (1 - p[0][0]) * (1 - p[1][0]) * p[2][0] *
                            (1 - p[0][1]) * p[1][1] * (1 - p[0][2]) * p[1][2];
                    //cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 8)
                {
                    P[z] += (1 - p[0][0]) * (1 - p[1][0]) * p[2][0] *
                            (1 - p[0][1]) * p[1][1] * (1 - p[0][2]) * p[2][2] * (1 - p[1][2]);
                    //  cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }

                if ((i + j + k) == 9)
                {
                    P[z] += (1 - p[0][0]) * (1 - p[1][0]) * p[2][0] *
                            (1 - p[0][1]) * p[2][1] * (1 - p[1][2]) * (1 - p[0][2]) * p[1][2];
                    //  cout << P[z] << " ";
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "P= " << P << endl;
    return P;
}
```

как мне правильно записать значения `P[z]` в массив, а потом вывести его, чтобы массив `P[z]` состоял из 7 вероятностей?

Comment: Так у вас `P[z]` и так - массив. Чего еще не хватает?

Comment: Задача не описана. Значение `r` заранее не известно. Но, грубо говоря, у вас вычисляется что-то очень странное. По странным формулам. Например, при `r==3` у вас будет массив из 27 элементов (`i+j+k` будут пробегать ряд `3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7 4 5 6 5 6 7 6 7 8 5 6 7 6 7 8 7 8 9`). Так что у вас вопрос - "не скажу куда иду, но я заблудился, а прийти мне нужно во вторник". :) Сформулируйте, **что именно вы вычисляете**, потому что без этого мы не сможем рассказать вам, как правильно держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей. Все, что я могу сказать сейчас - я бы заменил лесенку `if` на один `switch`.